# How to force a character to be encoded as a array with rjson?

Tags: json, r

Better than a long text, lets start with an example:

```
library(rjson)
toJSON(list(names = c("paul")))
# [1] "{\"names\":\"paul\"}"
toJSON(list(names = c("paul", "henri")))
# [1] "{\"names\":[\"paul\",\"henri\"]}"
```

In the first example, names is a string while in the 2nd example names is an array. I would like to force R in this particular case to always render an array.

Note: I also tried the RJSONIO library, but this will really encode everything. For examply, I still want the country to be a String.

```
library(RJSONIO)
toJSON(list(county="France", names = c("paul")), asIs = T)
# [1] "{\n \"county\": [ \"France\" ],\n\"names\": [ \"paul\" ] \n}"
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the **very** similar package [RJSONIO](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJSONIO/index.html), you can use `asIs` parameter to represents single numbers as vectors (as it always happens in R) :

```
library(RJSONIO)
toJSON(list(names = c("paul")),asIs=TRUE)

# result:
# [1] "{\n \"names\": [ \"paul\" ] \n}"
```

Otherwise, if you want to stick with `rjson` package, you can exploit the fact that lists are always converted to vectors (even when they contain only one value) :
*(note that this holds also for `RJSON` package with `asIs = FALSE`, since, as I said, they're really similar)*

```
library(rjson)
toJSON(list(country="France", names = list("paul")))
# or: toJSON(list(country="France", names = as.list(c("paul"))))

# result:
[1] "{\"country\":\"France\",\"names\":[\"paul\"]}"
```

Comment: Added a solution involving rjson

Comment: The `list("paul")` made the difference. Thx.